# Wireless on Laptop no longer works. Finds Access Points, but connections are limited. Phone connects fine

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, netsh

Recently the WiFi on my laptop is no longer working. At home, I cannot connect to my home network, and the network at work does not connect either - **at both places I have *limited connections***

This all started yesterday, and I was trying to setup a laptop hotspot. I downloaded a Win8 app that allowed that, and it asked me to perform command line actions with **netsh**.
I did everything it said, but it did not work. I uninstalled the app, and have tried to reinstate the older settings.

**This issues happened after I tried to use that app**, so I have the feeling that the issues stems from the use of **netsh**.

Please help me get my wireless internet back on my laptop.

[image]

The picture shows that the networks cannot be identified at all.

Setup
 - Win 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Are your ip settings on automatic for the wireless nic?

Comment: try `netsh winsock reset` at commandline and try again

Comment: I tried `netsh winsock reset` and it asked me to restart my laptop. Didn't want to do that right then, so I tried the other suggestions of making sure the **IP address** was **Automatic**, and that worked. So I don't know if the `net winsock reset` command worked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the app that set a fixed IP for your wireless network adapter. You could check this by clicking on your network adapter Wi-Fi(...)

Properties -> Internet Protocol 4. Everything should be set to automatic.

Comment: This does appear to work right now at my job. I will double check at home to make sure.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. It had set a fixed IP address. Thanks!